# How to delete contact only from selected group with UCMA 3.0

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010, ucma

When I try to delete a contact, stored in some group with

`_contactGroupServices.BeginDeleteContact` -> `_contactGroupServices.EndDeleteContact`

it's deleting from each group in contact list.

Is it possible to delete this contact only from one selected group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ContactGroupServices.BeginUpdateContact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh383885.aspx) method (and the corresponding `EndUpdateContact`).

This method takes a [`Contact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.contactsgroups.contact_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx) parameter, which in turn has a collection of group numbers called [`GroupIds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.contactsgroups.contact.groupids_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx).

The workflow would be:

1. Get the `GroupId` of the group you want to remove the contact from.
2. Get the `Contact` entry you want to remove from the group.
3. Remove the `GroupId` from his collection of `GroupIds`.
4. Call `BeginUpdateContact` with the new contact details.